# Sequential Forward Selection in Weka

Tags: wrapper, weka, feature-selection

I am trying to make attribute selection in Weka. But I want to apply sequential forward selection and sequential backward selection as a feature selection technique. 
What should I select as an attribute evaluator and search method?

Thank you for helping...

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. If you want to write Java code to integrate with Weka, that's OK. But if you need help using Weka, you're better off asking somewhere else like https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can use many different attribute evaluators with forward or backward selection. Forward and backward selectin are the _Search Method_  not the evaluator. Both forward and backward selection are available through the Search Method `BestFirst`